# Python Selenium Webdriver doesn't refresh html after changing dropdown value in AJAX pages

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I'm trying to scrape an AJAX webpage using Python and Selenium. The problem is, when I change the dropdown value, the page content changes according to my selection, but the selenium returns the same old html code from the page. I'd appreciate if anyone can help. Here is my code:

```html
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time

url = "https://myurl.com/PATH"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)

# change the dropdown value
sprintSelect = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("dropdown-select"))
sprintSelect.select_by_visible_text("DropDown_Value2")

html = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML")
print(html)
```

Comment: Selenium will only wait for a standard page load.  Since javascript is populating the page, you need to wait for the changes by either sleeping or testing for certain expected conditions using a WebDriverWait.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wait for the ajax to load the website after your selection.
Try to put implicit or explicit wait after selection.

`driver.implicitly_wait(10)  # 10 seconds`

or if you know the tag/id etc. of the web element you want, try the explicit

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "some_ID"))
```